# jQuery Autocomplete ComboBox Options Echo'd by PHP Getting Removed when Match Typed

Tags: php, jquery, combobox

Currently I have a combobox which options gets echo'd by PHP since the values are in an array. The code of the combobox is as follows:

```
    <div class="ui-widget">
        Project
        <br>
        <select id="combobox">
            <?php
                foreach($projects as $value)
                {
                    echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when a user types into the combobox he gets a dropdown-list with all the entries of the array that match the text the user typed in the combobox.

The user can then select an option from the dropdown-list or choose to type the entry completely(but it needs to mach the entries in the dropdown-list).

To achieve all this i am currently using the Autocomplete function of jQuery.
All the code that I am using to achieve this can be watched here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox.

The code for the combobox I use is as follows:

```
  <script>
  (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },

          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );

  $(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  });
  </script>
```

The problem that I am having right now is when a user types text in the combobox and the dropdown-list appears and he fully types out an entry of the dropdown-list the combobox still gets cleared. This is not supposed to happen. Whenever the user clicks on the combobox the item doesn't get cleared.

To make is a bit clearer here is an image of the combobox:

[image]

So above you can see the combobox. Whenever a user types something he gets a dropdown-list with all the results matched(project 1, project 10).

The problem that I am having right now is when a user types out "project 1" without clicking on the item in the dropdown-list the text in the combobox still gets removed by the Autocomplete function in jQuery.

If the user clicks on the item then there is no problem at all.

Funny thing is that the Autocomplete function works without any problems if I don't echo the option elements with PHP.

so:

```
<option value="project 1">project 1</option>
<option value="project 2">project 2</option>
<option value="project 3">project 3</option>
```

instead of:

```
foreach($projects as $value)
{
    echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
```

TO

```
echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
```

Comment: I changed it to: echo "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";. It still gets deleted when I type out a match.

Comment: Do you might have some other ideas what seem the be the cause of this problem?

Comment: With output you mean like the source of the html of the page?